# For a cms/block entity, why are the subordinate data deleted from cms_page_store explicitly?

Tags: database, cms, model, mysql

`cms/block` entities have a join table `cms_block_store`, the records in which link a given block to one or more stores. Prior to CE 1.6, the resource model [`Mage_Cms_Model_Mysql4_Block` (link)](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.5.1.0/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Mysql4/Block.php) does not separately remove these records before the entity is deleted, effectively relying on the cascade to remove them. As of 1.6.0.0, the relocated resource model explicitly removes these records in [`Mage_Cms_Model_Resource_Block::_beforeDelete` (link)](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.6.0.0/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Resource/Block.php#L52) *before* the entity is deleted from `cms_block`:

```
protected function _beforeDelete(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object)
{
    $condition = array(
        'block_id = ?'     => (int) $object->getId(),
    );

    $this->_getWriteAdapter()->delete($this->getTable('cms/block_store'), $condition);

    return parent::_beforeDelete($object);
}
```

Is there an apparent reason for performing this operation in two separate queries rather than relying on the cascade as it did before?

Comment: Is the Magento core team reading here?

Comment: I would hope so! I'll wait a couple of days and ping some of them if we don't get any good answers here.

Comment: maybe the interns that refactored the code thought this is a good idea... move some things out of the database, keep the logic at the code level.

Comment: so time to ping them :-)

Comment: @Alex - I'll be hanging out with them in LA this weekend and will update here.

Comment: Was there any update on this?

Comment: Nothing conclusive. Your answer seems the best.

Answer (score 3):

To me this most likely has to do with the swap to a relational database management system (RDBMS). Relying on the database cascading functionality could be problematic in different systems, so the logic has been added manually in the new Resource model.

The same can be seen in the `Mage_Cms_Model_Resource_Page::_beforeDelete()` method and the `Mage_Poll` and `Mage_Review` models too (although these occur in the `_afterSave()` methods.

[Read more about Magento's swap to RDBMS here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/images/uploads/RDBMS_Guide.pdf)